# Is there a way to go from Jquery Deferred/Promise to When-JS Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred, es6-promise, when-js

I would like to use When-JS capability out of the promise returned by a jquery ajax call. Is there a conversion scheme ?

Edit 1

https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Promises/A+ promises like When promises have this functionality by-design and they are built to assimilate jQuery thenables.

In order to convert any foreign thenable (like a jQuery promise) to a when promise, just wrap it in [`when`](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#when):

```
when($.get(...)).then(...
```

> `when(x)` - get a trusted promise for `x`. If `x` is a foreign thenable, a returns a promise that follows `x`.

How thenables are *assimilated* is well specified in [the Promises/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/) spec:

> The promise resolution procedure is an abstract operation taking as input a promise and a value, which we denote as `[[Resolve]](promise, x)`. If `x` is a `then`able, it attempts to make promise adopt the state of `x`, under the assumption that `x` behaves at least somewhat like a promise. Otherwise, it fulfills promise with the value `x`.